# Univesal Coefficient Theorem for $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory

The UCT theorem is shown in the sreenshot. I have a question : What is the definition of $Ext_{\Bbb Z}^1(K_{*}(A),K_{*}(B))$? Does it have a relationship with Tor functor?[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the Ext functor? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor

Comment: [Ext to Hom is the same as Tor to the tensor product.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor)

Comment: As others have mentioned, its a functor. But you can think of it as literally just the group of extensions. See for example Theorem 12 of section 17.1 in Dummit & Foote. In this case though, you want to keep track of the grading.